# How to sync to a sub directory in svn mirror？

Tags: svn, mirror, svnsync

I want to mirror a sub directory in master svn, and ensure the directory of mirror as same as the master svn, for example:

a sub directory in master svn:

> http ://X.X.X.X/svn/repo/a/b/c/d/....../subdir

sync to svn mirror:

> http ://Y.Y.Y.Y/svn/repo/a/b/c/d/....../subdir

But `svnsync init` report the following error:

> svnsync: E000022: Session is rooted at 'http ://Y.Y.Y.Y/svn/repo/a/b/c/d/....../subdir'

but the repos root is 'http ://Y.Y.Y.Y/svn/repo'

How to sync to a sub directory in svn mirror from the sub directory in master svn? Even though other way without svnsync.Thank you!

There are too many files in the other directorys in master svn, and they are useless for svn mirror.